# determine if powershell called the running exe?

Tags: powershell

From a running exe, how can one easily determine whether the exe was invoked from powershell? I've not found a predefined environment variable that is a reliable indicator.

My specific issue is that I'm trying to modify PATH and other env vars in an existing PS session from the exe (a Go static linked exe) by creating a "runner" .bat/.ps1 that mangles the env vars of the currently running cmd.exe or PS. If the exe was called from PS, I'll create a .ps1. If the exe was called from cmd.exe, I'll create a .bat. Ideally, I'd use a .bat with something like the following to handle PS:

```
rem This doesn't work
powershell -C "& { $env:FAKE_PATH_2='C:\ruby193\bin' }"

rem This also doesn't work
powershell -C "& { [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FAKE_PATH_3', 'Sneaky 1') }"

rem This also doesn't work
powershell -C [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FAKE_PATH_4', 'Sneaky 2')
```

but none of the above propagate the env vars to existing PS session. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require wrapper .bat/.ps1 scripts to setup and call the exe.

Any creative, low-complexity ideas?

Comment: Is your question how to determine that the exe was launched by powershell, or how to have the exe change the environment of the powershell process that launched it?

Comment: My goal is change the env of the running powershell instance that launched the exe. I currently think I need to create runner .bat or .ps1 script to do it and need the exe to know how it was called in order to create the correct "flavor" of runner script. Open to all ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to find the parent process ID and then determine if that is PowerShell.  I'll show an example here in PowerShell but you would need to convert that to the appropriate WMI API for your EXE:

```
$parentPid= (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId='$pid'").ParentProcessId
(Get-Process -Id $parentPid).ProcessName
```

That said, the rest of the question isn't very clear to me.  Executing this:

```
powershell -C "& { [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FAKE_PATH_3', 'Sneaky 1') }"
```

Starts a *new* PowerShell EXE and doesn't modify an existing PowerShell session. In fact, modifying an existing EXE's env block is going to be tricky.  And if the EXE doesn't monitor env block changes via WM_SETTINGCHANGE, it just won't work unless you get help from the EXE itself (like having PowerShell check for some sentinel to tell it to modify its env vars).

Comment: Hmm, creating a [simple example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5713692/) with a .bat runner to show what I'm trying to do sadly pulled the rug out from under this one. Passing `/c` or `/k` doesn't matter, likely as everything's happening in a subshell. Bad assumption...back to the drawing board ;)